# Create Observable that behaves like CombineLatest but only emit the value of the source that just fired

Tags: javascript, rxjs, system.reactive, reactivex

I would like to create an observable which takes N observable sources and transform them whith an N-ary function. The onNext() of this observable will call this function whenever one of the source observables emits an item, like this:  f(null,null,null,o3.val,null,null) where o3 is the source which just emitted a value.

Is like the combineLatest where the f is called with the last emitted values from all the sources combined together but here in the f we get null value for all the others.

The body of the f could act like a switch:

```
 function f(v1,v2,...vn) {
        if (v1) { ... }
        else if(v2) { ... }
    }
```

Is this possible? There are other way round for accomplish this behaviour?

Comment: so you want it to emit an array of `null`s but only at the index of the source Observable that just emitted you want its value?

Comment: yes it could be a way

Comment: It seems odd that you have `n` observables that you combine into a single array of values and then you use a series of `if` statements to choose a code path based on the value emitted. Why not just have `n` observables with `n` subscriptions to the code you need?

Comment: You would need to select the values according to some time slice. Otherwise if they consistently produced values simultaneously you would be unnecessarily forcing sequential processing.

Comment: Isn't this basically just `merge`?

Comment: @Asti: Yes is a merge but with a tag attached to each element that let you distinguish to which of the N source observables the item just emitted belongs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to think about something like this

```
const obsS1 = obsSource1.pipe(map(data => [data, 'o1']));
const obsS2 = obsSource2.pipe(map(data => [data, 'o2']));
....
const obsSN = obsSourceN.pipe(map(data => [data, 'oN']));

merge(obs1, obs2, ..., obsN)
.subscribe(
  dataObs => {
    // do what you need to do
    // dataObs[0] contains the value emitted by the source Observable
    // dataObs[1] contains the identifier of the source Observable which emitted last
  }
)
```

Comment: It could be but i don't understand how the code works, probably is the pipe operator any reference to it? It's the same thing of: https://blog.hackages.io/rxjs-5-5-piping-all-the-things-9d469d1b3f44

Comment: @Fruff I am not using the `pipe` operator here. I am using the `merge` function  provided by RxJs (`import {merge} from 'rxjs';`). The snippet I provided works like this: in the `dataObs` variable you have an array of 2 elements - the firs one is the value emitted, the second one an ID which identifies the source Observable which emitted the value, which is the 'tag' you are referring to in your last comment.